# muting AVAudioPlayer from SKScene while its playing in ViewController

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, sprite-kit, volume

I have an AVAudioPlayer set to loop indefinitely in the ViewController.m.
My question is how would I go about muting the AVAudioPlayer from an SKScene

```
//ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Space theme2"  ofType:@"mp3"]];
    _music = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [_music prepareToPlay];
    [_music setVolume:0.5];
    _music.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_music play];
```

so the AVAudioPlayer is playing in ViewController.m and needs to be muted/unmuted in SKScene.

```
//SKScene.m

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Mute"]) {
    //Mute Music "[_music setVolume:0.0]; isn't doing anything"
    self.Mute.position = CGPointMake(-100, self.Mute.position.y);
    self.Unmute.position = CGPointMake(160, self.Unmute.position.y);
}
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Unmute"]) {
    //Unmute Music [_music setVolume:0.5]; isn't doing anything"
    self.Mute.position = CGPointMake(160, self.Mute.position.y);
    self.Unmute.position = CGPointMake(-100, self.Unmute.position.y);
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
//ViewController.m

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(stopMusic:)
                                                 name:@"StopMusic"
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playMusic:)
                                                 name:@"PlayMusic"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Space theme2"  ofType:@"mp3"]];
    _music = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [_music prepareToPlay];
    [_music setVolume:0.5];
    _music.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_music play];
}

- (void)stopMusic:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [_music stop];
}

- (void)playMusic:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [_music play];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

.

```
// Scene.m:

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Mute"]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"StopMusic" object:self];
    self.Mute.position = CGPointMake(-100, self.Mute.position.y);
    self.Unmute.position = CGPointMake(160, self.Unmute.position.y);
}
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Unmute"]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"PlayMusic" object:self];
    self.Mute.position = CGPointMake(160, self.Mute.position.y);
    self.Unmute.position = CGPointMake(-100, self.Unmute.position.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of NSNotification or delegate methods. You can check them up [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [here](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002).